# If 'nb-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, nebular

I am having trouble setting up nebular sidebar, as i am getting error:

```
If 'nb-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

ERROR in src/app/pages/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:5:2 - error NG8001: 'nb-card' is not a known element:

1. If 'nb-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nb-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

feature module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { NbSidebarModule, NbLayoutModule } from '@nebular/theme';

import {
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbProgressBarModule,
  NbTabsetModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbIconModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbListModule,
  NbMenuModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbSidebarModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    NbCardModule,
    NbProgressBarModule,
    NbTabsetModule,
    NbUserModule,
    NbIconModule,
    NbSelectModule,
    NbListModule,
    NbMenuModule,
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NbThemeModule, NbLayoutModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { NbEvaIconsModule } from '@nebular/eva-icons';
import { NbSidebarModule, NbMenuModule} from '@nebular/theme';

import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/components/dashboard/dashboard.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'default' }),
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbEvaIconsModule,
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dashboard component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { NbMenuItem } from '@nebular/theme';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }


  items: NbMenuItem[] = [
    {
      title: 'Profile',
      expanded: true,
      children: [
        {
          title: 'Change Password',
        },
        {
          title: 'Privacy Policy',
        },
        {
          title: 'Logout',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Shopping Bag',
      children: [
        {
          title: 'First Product',
        },
        {
          title: 'Second Product',
        },
        {
          title: 'Third Product',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'Orders',
      children: [
        {
          title: 'First Order',
        },
        {
          title: 'Second Order',
        },
        {
          title: 'Third Order',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

dashboard component html:

```
<nb-layout>
  <nb-layout-header fixed>Company Name </nb-layout-header>

  <nb-sidebar>
    <nb-card>
      <nb-menu [items]="items" autoCollapse="true">
      </nb-menu>
    </nb-card>
  </nb-sidebar>

  <nb-layout-column>
    Page Content <button nbButton>Hello World</button>
  </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the dashboard.module should declare the dashboard.component as the NbCardModule is imported there.
atm it is declared in the app.module.

alternatively import the dashboard.module to the app.module