Nebular Theme Not Working with Angular 16 - 'nb-card-body' is Not a Known Element
I'm trying to integrate the Nebular theme into my Angular 16 project, but I'm encountering issues where it doesn't seem to work as expected. Specifically, after compilation, The setup was working perfectly with Angular 15 and Nebular 11. However, after upgrading to Angular 16, it started throwing this error.
1.If 'nb-card-body' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

If 'nb-card-body' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1)Has anyone successfully integrated Nebular with Angular 16?
2)Are there any known compatibility issues or specific configurations needed for Angular 16?
3)What troubleshooting steps can I take to resolve this issue?
Angular version: 16
Nebular version tried: 11 , 12, 13
Steps I followed:
1)Installed Nebular using npm install @nebular/theme.
2)Imported NbThemeModule.forRoot in my AppModule.
3)Added Nebular styles to angular.json.
4)Tried using some Nebular components in my templates.

Import NbCardModule to your feature module. Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64263228/795683

Thank you for the suggestion!
I did check the module declarations, and the NbCardModule is indeed imported in the correct module where Component is declared. The setup was working perfectly with Angular 15 and Nebular 11. However, after upgrading to Angular 16, it started throwing this error.
Any further insights would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue on stackblitz (for instance)

@Vaishnavi check if the component where you are getting the error is a standalone component, then you need to add NbCardModule to the imports array inside the component decorator object
